# Datatype-generic zippers and unfolds in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless, algebraic-data-types

What's the state-of-the-art in Scala w.r.t. datatype generic versions of a) zippers and b) unfolds/anamorphisms?

My specific interest is:

- The ability to automatically derive zippers and unfolds from sealed
  class hierarchies with minimal end-user effort.
- The ability to manipulate the zipper in a manner not known at compile-time   (e.g. traversing to a randomly-chosen point in the structure).

Shapeless gives a [generic zipper example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/zipper.scala) from the `future directions' section of  ["Scrap Your Zippers: A Generic Zipper for Heterogeneous Types", Michael D. Adams](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN8qn9lanKAhVGoA4KHau4CmkQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmichaeldadams.org%2Fpapers%2Fscrap_your_zippers%2F&usg=AFQjCNGtTap-ZDANWsn8OMc0aEq1JyEeyg&sig2=iWka2F-Wvow2wP_llfMz7A), but this requires that the end-user express their datatype in terms of HLists.

The [Cats](https://github.com/non/cats) library appears to have support for generic unfolds via [BiFunctors](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/datatype-generic-programming.html), but it's not clear to me whether, for some datatype `X`, it's necessary/possible to generate the required `GenericX` subclasses of `Fix` automatically.

Comment: shapeless provides a zipper for any product-like type with a `Generic` representation. The representation type will be an `HList` because the represented type is a product type. The reason that the example uses `HList` explicitly is because the zipper doesn't currently support types which have a coproduct representation, so embedded `List`s, which would need a coproduct representation, can't be navigated through. It's on my TODO list to extend zipper to handle coproduct types as well, and if you'd be interested in taking a look at it I'd be happy to advise.